# GROUP BY and get the columns values into single row column

Tags: mysql, group-by, distinct, group-concat

i was thinking if possible to get all the values of using GROUP BY room. example i have a tables named subject , room and classroom

table **subject**

```
   subject_id | subject_name
    -------------------
        1     | math
        2     | science
        3     | english
```

table **room**

```
    room_id | room_name
   -------------------
       1    | sunflower
       2    | cornflower
       3    | redflower
```

table **classroom**

```
    id | room_id | subject_id 
   -------------------
    1  | 1       | 1          
    2  | 1       | 2
    3  | 1       | 3
```

now the query. not sure if the query im used was correct or enough querying.. but the outputed query show expecting not that

```
SELECT * FROM classroom 
LEFT JOIN subject ON classroom.subject_id = subject.subject_id
LEFT JOIN room ON classroom.room_id = room.room_id 
GROUP BY room_name
```

now the output i want to expecting like this

**classroom**

```
room_name | subject_name 
------------------------
sunflower | math
          | science
          | english
```

it should grouping by sunflower into one row column

Comment: This isn't what GROUP BY does. Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: oh sorry thought it was group by. i dont know if possible to achieve the output i want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GROUP BY` is designed to reduce the number of rows and to enable aggregations for those rows. In your case the following query, **without** `group by` produces:

```
SELECT room_name, subject_name
FROM classroom 
LEFT JOIN subject ON classroom.subject_id = subject.subject_id
LEFT JOIN room ON classroom.room_id = room.room_id 

+-----------+--------------+
| room_name | subject_name |
+-----------+--------------+
| sunflower | english      |
| sunflower | math         |
| sunflower | science      |
+-----------+--------------+
```

So there isn't much point in using `GROUP BY`, but if we do, this is the result:

```
SELECT room_name, subject_name
FROM classroom 
LEFT JOIN subject ON classroom.subject_id = subject.subject_id
LEFT JOIN room ON classroom.room_id = room.room_id 
GROUP BY room_name, subject_name

+-----------+--------------+
| room_name | subject_name |
+-----------+--------------+
| sunflower | english      |
| sunflower | math         |
| sunflower | science      |
+-----------+--------------+
```

Note that the values are presented in both columns for every row. This IS both expected AND DESIRED.

`GROUP BY` is **not** a "presentation" tool that will suppress output of values in the first column, that is something that a "report tool" or "presentation layer" would be expected to handle.

[demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hsu6BjiU9zyngkVj1zKZPn/0)